# knockout add javascript object to an observable array

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have a below code for knockout binding:

HTML:

```
   <div data-bind="visible: people().length > 0">
    <div data-bind="foreach: people"> <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
 <span data-bind="text: forename"></span>
 <span data-bind="text: surname"></span>

        <button data-bind="click: $root.removePerson">Remove</button>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: Person">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: title" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: forename" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: surname" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.addPerson">Add</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
   var my = my || {};
Person = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(null);
    self.forename = ko.observable(null);
    self.surname = ko.observable(null);
};
my.vm = function () {
    var people = ko.observableArray([]),
        addPerson = function (jh) {
            people.push(jh);
        },
        removePerson = function (jh) {
            people.remove(jh);
        };
    return {
        people: people,
        addPerson: addPerson,
        removePerson: removePerson
    };
}(new Person());

ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

I am struggling to add Person object into an observable array (people) and display it on top to create an array of people with add and remove functionality in it.

`jsFiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asad23/RvdA7/)

Can someone please advise what am I missing?

**Update**: I have tidied up code a little bit, now the issue can be seen on fiddle, that adding a single object update all the array objects and removing an object removes all the objects from array which is the problem. Thank for the help.

Comment: Is that just a typo where you have `people = function (p)` rather than `addPerson = function (p)`?  Are you seeing errors or what problem are you having?

Comment: I see a number of mistakes in this code. The one mentioned by RP Niemeyer, also you call applyBindings with 'my.vm'. In your bindings, this is considered the $root binding context. So your databindings that start with my. or vm. won't work. Also, you define my.Person as a function, then use it as the value of a with-binding. This makes no sense to me. Additionally, I don't get the part (new my.Person()); that you put behind the function my.vm.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer you guessed it right. Sorry I corrected the typo and created a js fiddle.

Comment: @Hans "new my.Person())" is there to add an initial object when viewmodel is loaded. I am trying to get the scope right, but it is giving an error: Cannot read property 'vm' of undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that you are always dealing with a single instance of a `Person`. So, you are adding, updating, and removing the same instance.

A better approach might be to use something like a `personForEditing` observable that contains a new person.  Then, when doing `addPerson` you would add this person to the observableArray and replace `personForEditing` with a new instance for the next entry. Based on your code something like:

```
my.vm = function () {
    var people = ko.observableArray([]),
        addPerson = function (jh) {
            people.push(jh);
            personForEditing(new Person());
        },
        removePerson = function (jh) {
            people.remove(jh);
        },
        personForEditing = ko.observable(new Person())
    return {
        people: people,
        addPerson: addPerson,
        removePerson: removePerson,
        personForEditing: personForEditing
    };
}();
```

updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xms4d/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks RP Niemeyer. Answer from a knockout expert works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the variable people.

First it is set to an observable then to a function.

So the fault is here:

```
var people = ko.observableArray([]),
    people = function (p) {
        people.push(p);
    }, ... ;
```

Comment: this was a typo found by RP Niemeyer, I have corrected that and created and jsFiddle as well. Still no joy :(